# What is the difference between rails in_groups and in_groups_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Both of these methods sound like they should do the same thing but they don't appear to be aliases of each other. What is the difference between `in_groups` and `in_groups_of`?

- [`Array#in_groups`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups)
- [`Array#in_groups_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of)

Comment: One is basically slice, the other puts them in even-sized groups. Got it.

Comment: Another way to think of it: `in_groups(n)` returns a 2D array with `n` *rows*, whereas `in_groups_of(n)` returns a 2D array with `n` *columns*.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear.

**`in_groups`**`(number, fill_with = nil)`

> Splits or iterates over the array in ***number*** **of groups**, padding any remaining slots with fill_with unless it is false.

**`in_groups_of`**`(number, fill_with = nil)`

> Splits or iterates over the array in **groups of size** ***number***, padding any remaining slots with fill_with unless it is false.

Example:

```
# Splits in groups of 2
["a","b","c","d","e","f"].in_groups_of(2)
# => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]

# Splits in 2 groups
["a","b","c","d","e","f"].in_groups(2)
# => [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]
```